# Machine learning algorithm to work with body keypoints from image

Tags: regression, machine-learning, image-processing

I'm working on a project that will predict whether a person approaches and intends to interact.
There will be a camera and a pose estimation model that will analyze live frames and save the body parts keypoints of the people in the frame. Now I'm thinking which ML algorithm will learn from our sample videos and know if the person is willing and going to interact with what's under the camera.

Every 3-5 seconds with 2 frames each second will be the input of the model, which means 6-10 lists of keypoints, which are x and y coordinates of body parts in a frame. The idea is to process these lists to something meaningful that the model can learn from: The ankles are unnecessary for example, but the ratio between the shoulders in the first and last frames will be (meaning that the person got closer). Also the eyes are valuable.

I am expecting some output between 0 to 1 that represents the level of willingness to interact, so that's is also how I'm going to label the sample training.
My question is which ML model is suitable for this input and output and you think that will handle this kind of data well and give good predictions?

Comment: What do you wish to learn from these keypoints?

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear from the post, the goal is to detect when a person is intending to interact with the object who has the camera on it.

Comment: First is to try something simple, like RandomForest on features from independent windows. Or from 2 consecutive windows spaced a bit apart, so motion can be used for classification as well. Or feed in delta frames, the change in features between two timesteps

Comment: Do you think two frames will be enough as an instance to detect something like that, or maybe using more than that, like 5-6 and their delta frames? Also how would you do the labeling if I wish to get a 0 to 1 prediction? Label as 0 or 1 and then use a RandomForestRegressor?

Comment: No idea how well it performs, but always try the simplest thing that could possibly work first. Then increase complexity based on the learning that gives. Next step would be a proper sequence model, like an LSTM

Comment: You should label the event, object-interacrion at time t. Maybe mark different kinds of interactions if they exist, and also other annotations that could be useful. Like person entering / leaving field of view. Then you derive the labels to give the model from these richer annotations.